# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2080' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: unicode, anaconda, encode, codec

Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2080' in position 28: character maps to

Would you please help me?

Comment: Can you provide some context?  It looks like you are trying to print a Unicode character not supported by the current Windows code page.  Use an IDE that supports UTF-8 and you'll have better luck.

Comment: from IPython.display import Image
import pydot

graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph', rankdir="LR")

s0 = pydot.Node("S₀")
s1 = pydot.Node("S₁")

graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(s0, s0, label='a₀, p=0.5, r=5'))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(s0, s1, label='a₀, p=0.5, r=5'))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(s0, s1, label='a₁, p=1, r=10'))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(s1, s1, label='a₂, p=1, r=-1'))

Image(graph.create_png())

Comment: Image(graph.create_png())
  Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py, line 1662, in new_method
    format=f, prog=prog, encoding=encoding)
  File ...\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1836, in create
    self.write(tmp_name, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\j\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1754, in write
    f.write(s)

Comment: File ...\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2080' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, switch to Python 3.6+.  Examples below from a Windows console:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\u2080'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2080' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u2080')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python33x64\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2080' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u2080')
₀
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Tolonen my python version is 3.6! I did not understand how to solve it.

Comment: @SaNa So you comment that you're version is 3.6, you do not understand how to solve it, but you go on to mark it as the accepted answer? Did it, or did it not resolve your problem?